# How to filter using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having trouble writing LINQ as I'm a newbie:

How to write a LINQ query to display Process Date in dataItem2? When I add select {} in the query, I get an error message that IEnumerable is not used.

This is the data structures with dummy data:

```
List<DataItem> allData = new List<DataItem>();
var dataItem2 = new DataItem();
dataItem2.AddHeader("Process Date", "10/30/2014");
dataItem2.AddHeader("ABC Rank", "None"); 
dataItem2.AddDataRow(new[] { "a2aaa0", "2x0", "c2ccc0" });
dataItem2.AddDataRow(new[] { "a2aaa1", "b2bbb1", "c2ccc1" });  
allData.Add(dataItem2);
```

This is the DataItem class:

```
 class DataItem
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    private readonly List<string[]> _rows = new List<string[]>();

    public IEnumerable<string> Headers
    {
        get { return _headers.Keys; }
    }

    public void AddHeader(string key, string value)
    {
        _headers.Add(key, value);
    }

    public string GetHeader(string key)
    {
        return _headers[key];
    }

    public string[] GetDataRow(int rowNumber)
    {
        return _rows[rowNumber];
    }

    public void AddDataRow(string[] row)
    {
        _rows.Add(row);
    }

    public int RowCount
    {
        get { return _rows.Count; }
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New item:");
        foreach (var header in Headers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", header, GetHeader(header));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
        {
            var row = GetDataRow(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < row.Length; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cell ({0}, {1}): {2}", i, j, row[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Offending code:

```
var typedQry = from b in allData.AsEnumerable() 
               select new DataItem { b.GetHeader("Status") }; 
Console.WriteLine(typedQry.ToList());
```

Comment: You can also show the LINQ that you are using?

Comment: How about, you know, showing us the line of code that generates the error instead of all your other irrelevant code?

Comment: var typedQry = from b in allData.AsEnumerable()
      select new DataItem
      {
         b.GetHeader("Status")
                              
      };
     Console.WriteLine(typedQry.ToList());

Comment: @user2142250 please post the relevant code to your question in the future.  I will do it for you now.

Comment: In your original question you say: `How to write a LINQ query to display Process Date in dataItem2?` but the sample code you posted doesn't seem to be trying to do that.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: I note in your example you don't add a header with a key of "Status" -- what exactly do you expect to happen?

Comment: Any time you “get an error message” it’s pretty important to tell us what the message is.

Comment: Since you admit you are new to LINQ, you may be interested in checking out the free chapters we have available for [LINQ in Action](http://www.manning.com/marguerie/) particularly chapter 14 covering LINQ to DataSets that you appear to be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying `processDate` from `dataItem2` does not require LINQ...  Just user standard dot notation.  If this does not answer your question please post the relevant code.

Proper way:

```
dataItem2.ProcessDate
```

On the other hand if you have a collection of DataItem objects like below:

```
List<DataItem> items = PopulateMyItems();
```

then you can filter like so:

```
items.Where(t=>t.ProcessDate > TwoWeeksAgo);
```

Where `TwoWeeksAgo` would be a DateTime for two weeks ago.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Since Process Date is not a property in the DataItem property class, I modified your code to make it work: dataItem2.GetHeader("Process Date"). Your answer is marked as Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var typedQry = from b in allData.AsEnumerable() 
               select new { Status = b.GetHeader("Status") };
```

or

```
var typedQry = from b in allData.AsEnumerable() 
               where b.GetHeader("Status") != null
               select b;
```

depending on what you want to do.